# Apache localhost works great, except PHP is not responding

Tags: apache-2.2, php, mac, localhost, httpd.conf

I'm running Apache on Mac, PHP is installed, and I suspect something in the httpd.conf is not correctly set.

The symptom: Running PHP files in localhost yields PHP code, nothing else.

Running `apachectl -D DUMP_HOSTS` yields:

```
Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(13)Permission denied: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed. Problem: Missing `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a MAC running OS X 10.6.x

I just added the local IP to the "Listen" directive.  Changed Listen 80 -> Listen 127.0.0.1:80

Solved it for me.